# DataSource not found executing in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat

I'm implementing java web application using a datasource to access to PostgreSQL DB.

All work right but when I try to connect to DB in process running by java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor I obtain this exception:

```
it.zerounotribe.context.dbinterface.exception.DBException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:/comp/env/ContextDatasource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:].


at it.zerounotribe.context.dbinterface.ConnectionManager.getDatasourceConnection(ConnectionManager.java:138)
    at it.zerounotribe.context.dbinterface.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:96)
    at it.zerounotribe.context.dbinterface.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:83)
    at it.zerounotribe.context.dao.WebCronDAO.getWebCronsForRun(WebCronDAO.java:32)
    at it.zerounotribe.context.webcron.WebCronExecutor.run(WebCronExecutor.java:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:/comp/env/ContextDatasource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at it.zerounotribe.context.dbinterface.ConnectionManager.getDatasourceConnection(ConnectionManager.java:126)
    ... 11 more
```

Any suggestion are very appreciated.
Francesco

Comment: Are you sure you set the `Context.xml` correct? please share the `context.xml` and the servlet

Comment: If this is a JDBC `DataSource`, they typically have a `jdbc/` prefix before the data source name.

Comment: The DataSource run correctly normally. I obtain the exeception only in ThreadPoolExecutor.